# Ad is not showing after few days showing error "Ad failed to load :3"

Tags: admob

I have created a new app and then the ad unit keys. When I used those keys in our app it was working for few days. But now it is showing  "Ad failed to load : 3". I have created a new app also but still the same problem. Please help us to know the reason behind this?